# WordPress Featured images not displaying on Chrome browser in Windows PC

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, wordpress-featured-image

I'm using `WordPress 4.9.3` and the `Twenty Seventeen` theme for my website. I recently observed that many (everything except one) **featured images** stopped displaying when I access the website using `Google Chrome` browser from any Windows PC. However, the images are displaying correctly when I try to access the website on mobile phones-Safari (iPhone) and Chrome (Android phone) and Microsoft Edge (Windows PC).

1. Website accessed through Chrome from Windows PC-Featured image missing

[image: Website accessed through Chrome from Windows PC-Featured image missing]

2. Website accessed through Chrome from Android mobile phone- Featured image displayed

[image: Website accessed through Chrome from Android mobile phone- Featured image displayed]

3. Website accessed through Microsoft Edge from Windows PC-Featured image displayed
   [image: Website accessed through Microsoft Edge from Windows PC-Featured image displayed]

I have also tried out the solution provided [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6yCgM_nm4Ws)  by adding it to the Additional-CSS. But it did not help.

I would appreciate any help/guidance to resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your browser cache ? Because i have no problem to see your website’s images on chrome (67.0.3396.99) on a Windows PC

Comment: @A.Joahny Thanks for your response.I had tried clearing the browser cache; it did not help.

Comment: Have you tried to open directly an image url ? If it returns a 404 error, try to do CTRL+F5. If image appears try to reload the website page. The image appears ? If yes, you have a cache problem. You can try to load your page with incognito mode too.

Answer (score 0):

Some Chrome extensions can cause this problem, I have the same issue as well, you can try disabling adblock, screen recording app or VPN.

Comment: The AdBlock gets me every time. ;-)